# deploy on heroku failed because npm version is not the latest

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, npm

looks like heroku is using npm version 1.0.94

I have a dependency that require node 0.6.x, but npm 1.0.94 is 'based' on node 0.4.7

is there any workaround to solve this issue.

```
Installing dependencies with npm 1.0.94
       npm ERR! Unsupported
       npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: palette@0.0.1
       npm ERR! Required: {"node":"0.6.x"}
       npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.0.94","node":"0.4.7"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build your own node version for heroku with buildpacks.

fork and modify node version in https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs

also see http://blog.superpat.com/2011/11/15/running-your-own-node-js-version-on-heroku/

Answer (score 7):

The example listed @ http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js

worked for me when I modified the **package.json** to the following:

```
{
  "name": "node-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": ">=2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! However, as mentioned above and in the heroku docs: "Cedar user Node.js v0.4.7, so make absolutely sure you develop your app locally with this version."

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the version of node and npm in the package.json file.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Heroku Cedar doesn't use the latest version of node.js quite yet !

"Prerequisites

- Basic Node.js knowledge, including an installed version of Node.js and NPM.
- Your application must run on Node.js 0.4.7.
- Your application must use NPM to manage dependencies."

(seen on [Heroku Dev Center](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js))

So the problem is not only the npm version, but the node.js version as well !

You should verify if you really need the latest version of node and if so, the only answer on using heroku is to wait for an update !

Best regards !

Comment: this is incorrect. you can build and package your own version of node for heroku